# Foundry Test Failing - FAIL. Reason: WRONG_FROM

Tags: solidity, unittesting, foundry

I've been trying to get this test to work since a long time, out of 8 this is the only one that fails, am not able to understand what goes wrong even by using the more verbose test promt (-vvvv)

test code:

```
function testCanBuyListing() public {
        uint256 userBalance = address(this).balance;
        nft.transferFrom(address(this), user, nftId);

        uint256 listingId = opensea.list(nft, nftId, 1 ether);

        vm.prank(user);
        opensea.buyListing{value: 1 ether}(listingId);
    }
```

error (along with traces)

```
 [141591] OpenseaTest::testCanBuyListing() 
    ├─ [32624] TestNFT::transferFrom(OpenseaTest: [0xb4c79dab8f259c7aee6e5b2aa729821864227e84], 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001, 1) 
    │   ├─ emit Transfer(from: OpenseaTest: [0xb4c79dab8f259c7aee6e5b2aa729821864227e84], to: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001, id: 1)
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [94435] Opensea::list(TestNFT: [0x185a4dc360ce69bdccee33b3784b0282f7961aea], 1, 1000000000000000000) 
    │   ├─ emit NewListing(listing: (0x185a4dc360ce69bdccee33b3784b0282f7961aea, 1, 0xb4c79dab8f259c7aee6e5b2aa729821864227e84, 1000000000000000000))
    │   ├─ [842] TestNFT::transferFrom(OpenseaTest: [0xb4c79dab8f259c7aee6e5b2aa729821864227e84], Opensea: [0xce71065d4017f316ec606fe4422e11eb2c47c246], 1) 
    │   │   └─ ← "WRONG_FROM"
    │   └─ ← "WRONG_FROM"
    └─ ← "WRONG_FROM"
```

Comment: Take a look at the [startPrank](https://book.getfoundry.sh/cheatcodes/start-prank?highlight=startPrank#startprank) cheatcode.

Comment: no worries. I can also recommend you read the [Foundry Book](https://book.getfoundry.sh/) from cover to cover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error might be from either `address(this)` and `user` is the same address or `address(this)` might have no nft